# image shuffling and slicing

Tags: image-processing

This is my code for slicing my 512*512 image into a cube of 64*64*64 dimension. but when i reshape it again into a 2D array why is it not giving me the original image.am i doing something incorrect please help.

```
 clc; 

 im=ind2gray(y,ymap);
 % im=imresize(im,0.125);
 [rows ,columns, colbands] = size(im)



    end
  image3d=reshape(image3d,512,512);
  figure,imshow(uint8(image3d));
```

Comment: There is importance to order you crate the slices. Try changing row and col loops. First do for col and than for row.

Comment: But simply switching rows and columns doesn't fix the code.

Comment: Your formatting of the matrix for slicing is not what reshape will expect later, because MATLAB function reshape expect that you have traversed coloumn wise but you are formulating your cube with half of coloumnwise and half of row wise operation. So when finally you are reshaping back it is reshaping wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just a small hint.

```
P(:,:,1) = [0,0;0,0]
P(:,:,2) = [1,1;1,1]
P(:,:,3) = [2,2;2,2]
P(:,:,4) = [3,3;3,3]

B = reshape(P,4,4)

B =

     0     1     2     3
     0     1     2     3
     0     1     2     3
     0     1     2     3
```

So you might change the slicing or do the reshaping on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question right, you can look into the code below to perform the same operation.

```
% Random image of the provided size 512X512
imageX = rand(512,512)
imagesc(imageX)

% Converting the image "imageX" into the cube of 64X64X64 dimension
sliceColWise = reshape(imageX,64,64,64)
size(sliceColWise)

% Reshaping the cube to obtain the image original that was "imageX", 
% in order to observe that they are identical the difference is plotted
imageY = reshape(sliceColWise,512,512);
imagesc(imageX-imageY)
```

n.b: From MATLAB help you can see that the reshape works column wise

> reshape(X,M,N) or reshape(X,[M,N]) returns the M-by-N matrix 
>       whose elements are taken columnwise from X. An error results 
>       if X does not have M*N elements.